# Filtering in Datatables

Tags: filter, grid, data, data-tables

Currently, we are having issues with filters on our datagrids and the space they take in the screen.

[image]

I think the way they are used right now they take a lot of space that's not needed.

I would personally do something else.

I've got multiple options to go on this matter.

**1:** Filters in datagrid.

**2:** Show the most used options and hide the others till needed.

[image]

Which one should I use and for what reasons?

**EDIT**

Option 1 is where the filters are placed below the table headers inside the datagrid to save space.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding both the image and description for option 1.

Comment: edited the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally prefer to have the main search criteria, like dates on top of the grid. That would be the criteria that makes up the where-clause in your data-set (if you use any RDMS that is).

Then I'd use whatever important filters that are required beneath the column-headers. That is to say that not every filter might need a filter.

The three ways I usually use filtering and grouping of grids are these:

- **Filtering**: either using numeric or textual input to filter an already loaded data set. For instance searching for particular names either containing letters or that are equal to the search-criteria (ie. inclusive / exclusive searches).
- **Grouping**: Allowing the user to drag and drop (preferably using direct manipulation) column headers in a field to group rows depending on the dropped header. An example being dragging a date into the group-field which would group all rows in particular dates.
- **Sorting**: Clicking a column header should sort it in Asc-Desc order so that the user more rapidly can find what he / she is looking for. Sorting is preferably implemented where the column's field-values can only be a few different values (boolean, for instance), but can be implemented on any.

You don't want to clutter the fields with filters, though so only put them wherever you actually think the user would be using them. It's my belief that the focus should be on the data you are displaying and the functionality should be there to help the user find the data that is relevant to complete his task.

Here is an example of a grid that we use where I work.[image]